# how to resolve this issue - Unknown provider: UsersProvider <- Users

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

This was working yesterday but not now!!!! please suggest. ng-app is included in my html. file

I have included all configuration files and not sure why is this happening???

here is my app.js

```
'use strict';


// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services   
angular.module('myApp', [
'ngRoute',
'myApp.filters',
'myApp.services',
 'myApp.directives',
'myApp.controllers'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller:    'MyCtrl1'});
 $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller:        'MyCtrl2'});
 $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
 }]);
```

controller.js

```
 'use strict';

 /* Controllers */

  angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
    controller('MyCtrl1', function($scope, Users) {
        $scope.allusers = Users.query();
    })
    .controller('MyCtrl2', [function() {

        }]);
```

services.js

```
  'use strict';

  var userServices = angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']);

  var commentServices = angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']);

   userServices.factory('Users', function($resource) { 
   return $resource('http://localhost:8080/PingleBackend/webresources/users', {}, {
    query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
    //        create: {method: 'POST'}
    }); 
    });






[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: UsersProvider <- Users
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$injector/unpr?p0=UsersProvider%20%3C-%20Users
http://localhost:8383/PingleFrontend/lib/angular/angular.js:3556 (23:27:33:392 | error)
at (anonymous function) (app/lib/angular/angular.js:9503:0)
at (anonymous function) (app/lib/angular/angular.js:6914:0)
at nodeLinkFn (app/lib/angular/angular.js:6274:0)
at compositeLinkFn (app/lib/angular/angular.js:5682:0)
at publicLinkFn (app/lib/angular/angular.js:5587:0)
at boundTranscludeFn (app/lib/angular/angular.js:5701:0)
at controllersBoundTransclude (app/lib/angular/angular.js:6292:0)
at update (app/lib/angular/angular-route.js:873:0)
at (anonymous function) (app/lib/angular/angular.js:12329:0)
at (anonymous function) (app/lib/angular/angular-route.js:556:0)
at (anonymous function) (app/lib/angular/angular.js:11033:0)
at (anonymous function) (app/lib/angular/angular.js:11033:0)
at (anonymous function) (app/lib/angular/angular.js:11119:0)
at (anonymous function) (app/lib/angular/angular.js:12045:0)
at (anonymous function) (app/lib/angular/angular.js:11871:0)
at (anonymous function) (app/lib/angular/angular.js:12151:0)
at done (app/lib/angular/angular.js:7909:0)
at completeRequest (app/lib/angular/angular.js:8110:0)
at (anonymous function) (app/lib/angular/angular.js:8056:0)
```

> 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['myApp.services'])
```

**UPDATE**

You have got two modules with the same name

```
var userServices = angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']);
var commentServices = angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']);
```

**Don't use globals !**

:)

Comment: though I have added myApp.services in my services.js already            var userServices = angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']);